Posts made by facebook app not visible when logged out from admin account
I've recently encountered an issue with a Facebook app (A php scriot) I've developed, and I'm seeking advice on how to troubleshoot it effectively. Here's the situation:
I've created a php script using the Graph API Explorer in Facebook Developer account, which automatically posts content to a Facebook page. While the app works perfectly fine when I'm logged into my admin account, I've noticed that the posts made by the app are not visible when I log out.
My facebook app mode is still in development mode. Could it be the reason?
I've checked the privacy settings of the posts, and they're set to "Public." Additionally, I've ensured that the app has the necessary permissions, including pages_manage_posts and pages_read_engagement. However, despite these precautions, the posts remain invisible to users who are not logged into an admin account.

Does this answer your question? Facebook Graph Page Posts Successful But Not Showing On Feed For All
